# Is rotating magnets around a copper band a valid electric generator design?

Tags: generator

I am thinking of making my own small-scale vertical wind turbine, and as a result I have been thinking about designs.

I have been thinking about the following design in which a number of permenant magnets are attached around a central rotating disk, while around this rotating disk is a copper band:

[image]

Is this a valid/efficient design?

If this is not a valid generator design, what would be a better one?

Even though there are 8 magnets placed in the central disk, this is not representative of what it will actually look like, eg - there may be fewer or more magnets depending on magnetic field, size, etc.

Comment: While what you propose does fit the definition of a generator I think you will find that this will be highly INEFFICIENT.  Companies have been refining the design of PM generators for many years and you will probably get much better results by using a commercially made generator.

Comment: TBH, I do not see how exactly it is going to generate anything. There is no magnetic flux change through the "copper band".

Comment: Get a magnet, some insulated wire and a sensitive meter - analog is better than digital for this type of study - and try out some experiments to demonstrate Faraday's laws of electromagnetic induction. You're missing the basics. See https://www.electrical4u.com/faraday-law-of-electromagnetic-induction/ for some ideas.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magfor.html#c2